# How to avoid Alarm manager overriding with same intervals of time with different message using dynamically?

Tags: java, android, sms, alarmmanager

What happens if we select same intervals for two different message its not sending the respective manner,its taking the first message content and sending the second sms timing.
I want to send different sms with same intervals using dynamically.

MyAlaramactivity.java

else if (mytime.equals("Every 5 Minutes")) {

```
                        editor1.putString("p1",edittextSmsNumber.getText().toString());
                        editor1.putString("m1",edittextSmsText.getText().toString());
                        editor1.commit();
                        edittextSmsNumber.setText(" ");
                        edittextSmsText.setText(" ");


                        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

                        calendar.set(datep.getYear(), datep.getMonth(),
                                datep.getDayOfMonth(),
                                timep.getCurrentHour(),
                                timep.getCurrentMinute(), 0);
                        Intent myIntent1 = new Intent(AndroidAlarmSMS.this,
                                MyAlarmService.class);
                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        bundle.putInt("service", 1);
                        myIntent1.putExtras(bundle);
                        //myIntent1.putExtra("service", "s1");
                        myIntent1.setData(Uri.parse("timer:myIntent1"));
                        pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getService(
                                AndroidAlarmSMS.this, 1, myIntent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                        AlarmManager alarmManager1 = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                        alarmManager1.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                                calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 2,
                                pendingIntent1);




                        // Millisec * Second *
                                                // Minute
                    } else if (mytime.equals("Every hour")) {
                        editor2.putString("p2",edittextSmsNumber.getText().toString());
                        editor2.putString("m2",edittextSmsText.getText().toString());
                        editor2.commit();
                        edittextSmsNumber.setText(" ");
                        edittextSmsText.setText(" ");
                        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

                        calendar.set(datep.getYear(), datep.getMonth(),
                                datep.getDayOfMonth(),
                                timep.getCurrentHour(),
                                timep.getCurrentMinute(), 0);
                        Intent myIntent2 = new Intent(AndroidAlarmSMS.this,
                                MyAlarmService.class);
                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        bundle.putInt("service", 2);
                        myIntent2.putExtras(bundle);
                        myIntent2.setData(Uri.parse("timer:myIntent2"));
                        pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getService(
                                AndroidAlarmSMS.this, 2, myIntent2, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                        AlarmManager alarmManager2 = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

                        alarmManager2.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                                calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 3,
                                pendingIntent2); 




This is my service class



public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
  super.onStart(intent, startId);
  Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
  //String status= b.getString("service");
  status = bundle.getInt("service", 0);


  if(i==2)
   {
   i++;
   Toast.makeText(this, "Hiii", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
   else
   {
       String share_pref_file = "IMS";
          SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(share_pref_file,
          Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
       if(status == 1)
       {
           String number = prefs.getString("p1", "");
           String message = prefs.getString("m1", "");
              //String message= prefs.getString("extraSmsText", "");

              Toast.makeText(this, "MyAlarmService.onStart()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              Toast.makeText(this,
                     number,
                     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

              SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
              smsManager.sendTextMessage(number, null, message, null, null);  
       }
       else if (status == 2)
       {
           String share_pref_file1 = "IMS2";
              SharedPreferences prefs2 = getSharedPreferences(share_pref_file1,
              Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
           String number = prefs2.getString("p2", "");
           String message = prefs2.getString("m2", "");
              //String message= prefs.getString("extraSmsText", "");

              Toast.makeText(this, "MyAlarmService.onStart()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              Toast.makeText(this,
                     number,
                     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              try{
                  SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    smsManager.sendTextMessage(number, null, message, null, null);  
                      Toast.makeText(this, "Message sent successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              }
              catch(Exception e)
              {
                  Toast.makeText(this,
                            "I will kill you enter correct number",
                             Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
              }


       }
```

Have to avoid alarammanager overriden for same intervals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i reviewed your code, as you want to set  multiple alarams first you have to create alaram manager array and change your code to like this.. first you create one global integer variable with name fivemin

```
else if (mytime.equals("Every 5 Minutes")) {
fivemin=fivemin+1;

AlarmManager[] alarmManager=new AlarmManager[24];


ArrayList<PendingIntent> intentArray = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();



Intent myIntent1 = new Intent(AndroidAlarmSMS.this,
                                    MyAlarmService.class);
                            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putInt("service", 1);
                    myIntent1.putExtras(bundle);


                            myIntent1.setData(Uri.parse("timer:myIntent1"));
                            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(
                                    AndroidAlarmSMS.this, fivemin, myIntent1,0);

                            alarmManager[fivemin] =  (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);        
                            alarmManager[fivemin].setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                                    calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 2,
                                    pendingIntent);

                            intentArray.add(pendingIntent);
```

Answer (score 3):

**Issue:**
Pending intents are overriding.

**Solution:**
You just need to provide `unique id` to each pending intent

**Example:**

You have already provided **`0`** as `id` in

```
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(
                                AndroidAlarmSMS.this, 0, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

So don't provide **`0`** again in next pending intent, use **`1 and 2`** instead of **`0`** like mentioned below:

```
pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getService(
                                AndroidAlarmSMS.this, 1, myIntent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getService(
                                AndroidAlarmSMS.this, 2, myIntent2, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

I hope it will be helpful !!

Comment: ,thanks for your answer,but i already changed the pending intent name different,now i put shared preference seperately for each one,that is working;now what it happens if we make different frequency like every 5minutes ,and every hours like that its working fine
but if we set 11.00 interval of every 5 minutes and 11.01 set as interval of every 5 minutes na,then that time its overridden

Comment: @KarthickM: you are checking condition like this: `status.equalsIgnoreCase("s1")` .but you have not passed `s1` or `s2` anywhere.check your code ,it is `1` and `2`

Comment: @KarthickM: kindly follow the standard practice while giving name to any variable.it is terrible to read

Comment: @Mehal Joisar,i forgot to update my service code,now you check it